# Dynamic Jackson fields filtering

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to implement wrapper class, that will be serialized by Jackson with omitting fields depending on runtime configuration:

```java
class Partial<T> {
    T value;
    List<String> fieldsToSkip;
}
```

This

```java
class Example{int a=1; int b=2; int c=3;}
new Partial(new Example(), asList("b"));
```

suppose to be serialized to `{"a":1, "c":3}`.

`@JsonUnwrapped` with `@JsonFilter` seems to be right approach here. The problem is that the filter works on `value` field level, where there's no access to host `Partial` instance.

What is the best way to implement such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can create at run time an `ObjectWriter` with a filter also defined at run time and use it to write the value in `Partial`:

```
 SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = 
     SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(new HashSet<>(partial.fieldsToSkip));
 FilterProvider fp = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("exampleFilter", filter);
 String text = objectMapper.writer(fp).writeValueAsString(partial.value);
```

and tell Jackson that this filter should be applied to `Example` class:

```
 @JsonFilter("exampleFilter")
 class Example{int a=1; int b=2; int c=3;}
```

You may want to change `fieldsToSkip` to a `Set<String>`

Comment: Thanks, Manos. This solution probably works, but is there a way to avoid mapper configuration for each particular serialization request? Im using it for Spring web response serialization, and afraid that applying this dynamic configuration might be tricky.

Comment: Yes it will be tricky. I believe [squiggly](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly) could help in your case. It works with spring, you just append query param like `&fields=a,c` at HTTP request and squiggly will tell jackson to only serliase these fields in response. Little to no extra coding required.